# Python xml duplicate a specific sub element and all sub elements and change its name

Tags: python, xml, copy, element

I built a full root tree with subelements from an xml and just need to duplicate a certain part with a name change before writing to the file, example

I tried using deepcopy but no luck.

example:

```
   <main ....>
     <head ....>
      <element 1 .... >
         <sub1 xxx>
            <sub1.2 xxxx>
               <sub1.2.1>
                  <sub1.2.1.1>
                  </sub1.2.1.1>
               <sub1.2.2>
               </sub1.2.2>
                .
                .
                .
      <element_1/>
     </head>
    </main>
```

The new root should look like

```
 <main ....>
 <head ....>
  <element_1 .... >
     <sub1 xxx>
        <sub1.2 xxxx>
           <sub1.2.1>
              <sub1.2.1.1>
              </sub1.2.1.1>
           <sub1.2.2>
           </sub1.2.2>
            .
            .
            .
  <element_1/>
```

The new root should look like below after copy:

```
  <new_copy_element .... >  #same data below as the one in element_1
     <sub1 xxx>
        <sub1.2 xxxx>
           <sub1.2.1>
              <sub1.2.1.1>
              </sub1.2.1.1>
           <sub1.2.2>
           </sub1.2.2>
            .
            .
            .
  <new_copy_element/>
 </head>
</main>
```

current code before cloning something like:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(input_filename, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

####    
for elem in root.getiterator():
    if not hasattr(elem.tag, 'find'): continue  # (1)
    i = elem.tag.find('}')
    if i >= 0:
        elem.tag = elem.tag[i+1:]
objectify.deannotate(root, cleanup_namespaces=True)


def write_xml(file, element):
    xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(element)).toprettyxml(indent="  ")
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        f.write(xmlstr)
        f.close()   
    
    
    
head = SubElement(root, 'head')


elem1 = SubElement(head, 'element_1')

elem1.set('xx', xx)
sub1 = SubElement(elem1, 'sub1')
sub1.set('xxx', "yyy")


for key, value in data.items():
    sub11 = SubElement(sub1, 'sub1.1')
    sub11.set('nnn', str(key))
    .
    .     
elem2 = SubElement(elem1, 'elem2')

.
.

write_xml(output_filename,root)
```

(I need to duplicate all data from elem1 but names it element_2 for example before or after I call write_xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you were right with using copy from deepcopy. I created a simple example of your xml and copied the element. Instead of printing you simply can call your writing function.

```
from lxml import etree
import copy

s = """<main>
 <head>
   <elem1>
    <sub1>Example</sub1>
   </elem1>
 </head>
</main>"""

file = etree.fromstring(s)
head = file.find("head")
for elem1 in file.findall(".//elem1"):
    dupe = copy.deepcopy(elem1) #copy <elem1> node
    dupe.tag = "new_copy_element"
    head.append(dupe) #insert the new node

print(etree.tostring(file,pretty_print=True, encoding=str))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I actually ended up doing, I thought it will be more resource consuming but it's ok.